# How to add section titles/headers in between form fields in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get my form to look like this:
except with empty checkboxes (could't find icons without a check)

Drive and Woods

☑ Driver
☑ 3-Wood
☑ 5-Wood

Irons
☑ 1-Iron
☑ 2-Iron
☑ 3-Iron
☑ 4-Iron
☑ 5-Iron

Wedges
☑ SW
☑ PW

I'm using Crispy Forms by the way.

I can only get the checkboxes going down without the headers and without spaces they look like this right now:
☑ Driver
☑ 3-Wood
☑ 5-Wood
☑ 1-Iron
☑ 2-Iron
☑ 3-Iron
☑ 4-Iron
☑ 5-Iron
etc...

my forms.py looks like this right now

```
class inputForms(forms.Form):
Driver  = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_3_wood = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_5_wood = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
Hybrid = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_1_iron = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_2_iron = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_3_iron = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_4_iron = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_5_iron = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_6_iron = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_7_iron = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_8_iron = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
_9_iron = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
SW = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
PW = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

my views.py looksl like this:

```
def inputsuser(request):
    forms = inputForms()
    return render(request, 'users/inputsuser.html', {'form': forms})
```

my template form looks like this:

```
    <form method="POST" style="margin-top:50px;" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <div class="row">
            <button class="btn green white-text">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Trying to get each group of checkboxes separated by a title or header

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using django-crispy-forms, you can use a FormHelper to get the result you want.

```
class inputForms(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Drive and Woods',
                'Driver',
                '_3_wood',
                '_5_wood'
            ),
            Fieldset(
                'Irons',
                '_1_iron',
                ...
            ), ...
        )
```

You'll need to use `{% crispy form %}` instead of `{{ form|crispy }}` in the template.